# <td> position is not fixed, it moves up and alignment breaks while generating html email body

Tags: html

I am generating a html email body for microsoft outlook in C# winforms, passing the html code to a string variable.

I am using  tags, in the email body I am displaying image on the left and text on the right-->dynamically i am retrieving rows from Database and adding li (bullets to it).

When the number of row increases the td which is containing the li data, that td's alignment in breaking. The td is moving up when the number of li increases.(Means the left side image is fixed but the right side text is moving up, so the text is not correctly to the image)

Used position:absolute/relative fixed the problem in .html page, when I test the same in outlook mailbox the  alignment still breaks.

Somebody help me.

```
string html =
    @"<table style=""float:left;width:900px;overflow:auto"">
            <tr>
                <td style=""float:left;margin-bottom:70px"">
                    <img src=""smiley.png"" alt=""smiley"" />                  
                </td>
                    <td style=""font-family:Calibri;margin-right:105px;margin-top:20px"">
                    <h2 style=""font-family:Calibri;font-size:15pt;font-weight:bold"">Smiley</h2>
                    <ul>
                <li>Forget the standard DIVs and CSS approach </li>
                            <li>Tables and multi-level nested tables are the way to go and there seems to be no limit on the levels of nested tables</li>
                            <li>so don’t be afraid to use them despite how counter-intuitive it may seem.</li>
                            <li>Divide your design up into rows and columns as you may have (like me) when first learning web development</li>
            </ul>          
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>"
```

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align: top`?

Comment: Thank you It worked!! I added `vertical-align: top` for image td tag and text td tag. Now I am getting the expected output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**answer to accept**

Use `vertical-align: top;` to align content inside `td`